# Gradle resolve ext properties in depedencies for multi-project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-project

I have the following multi-project structure (only the important parts are shown):

```
- project
    - build.gradle (file) 
    - settings.gradle (file)
    + module1 (dir)
    + module2 (dir)
```

*build.gradle*:

```
ext {
    groovyMajorVersion = 2.4
    groovyMinorVersion = 3
}
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyMajorVersion}.${groovyMinorVersion}'
        testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-${groovyMajorVersion}'
    }
}
```

*settings.gradle*:

```
include 'module1', 'module2'
```

When I run `gradle dependencies` from module1, I get the following error:

```
testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyMajorVersion}.${groovyMinorVersion} FAILED
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-${groovyMajorVersion} FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because inside the dependencies block you're wrapping the dependencies with apostrophes (`'`) rather than inverted commas (`"`), thus the parameters inside the dependencies do not get resolved. To fix, simply replace the the apostrophes with inverted commas, i.e.:

```
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyMajorVersion}.${groovyMinorVersion}"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-${groovyMajorVersion}"
```

Comment: Amnon Shochot, you are right. It was due to my yesterday changes where I replaced all " into ', and completely forgot about Groovy string interpolation. Thank you.